# Python: splitting a long text into chunks of strings, given character limit

Tags: python, string, list

Google speech to text has a 5000 character limit, while my text is about 50k character. I need to chunk the string based on a given limit without cutting off the words.

```
“Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don’t tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist—I really believe he is Antichrist—I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my ‘faithful slave,’ as you call yourself! But how do you do? I see I have frightened you—sit down and tell me all the news.”
```

How do I chunk this above string into a list of strings that are not over 20 characters without cutting off the words?

I looked at the `NLTK` library chunking section and didn't see anything there.

Comment: "without cutting off the words" - what does this mean? You mean you always want the splits to be in the white space between the words?

Comment: @Dan. yeah. that's right. Because i have to feed it through Google's text to speech API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A base-python approach would look 20 characters ahead, find the last bit of whitespace possible, and cut the line there. This isn't an incredibly elegant implementation of that, but it should do the job:

```
orig_string = “Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don’t tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist—I really believe he is Antichrist—I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my ‘faithful slave,’ as you call yourself! But how do you do? I see I have frightened you—sit down and tell me all the news.”
list_of_lines = []
max_length = 20
while len(orig_string) > max_length:
    line_length = orig_string[:max_length].rfind(' ')
    list_of_lines.append(orig_string[:line_length])
    orig_string = orig_string[line_length + 1:]
list_of_lines.append(orig_string)
```

Comment: It seems to be leaving out the last bit... i've change the `max_length` number and seems to be leaving out the end no matter what.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I accidentally forgot to add the last line, in which you just add whatever's left of `orig_string` to `list_of_lines`.

Comment: If there is a space at character 20, wouldn't this cut it one word to short? i.e. before doing the `rfind`, you should check if `orig_string[max_length] == ' '`.

Comment: @Dan good point - though an easier way of handling that might be to just set `max_length` to 21.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. This works. At first I was cursing Google for making the limit so low. Now I love it because I can break it up and multithread it and combine it and it's really fast how it converts.

Answer (score 7):

This is a similar idea to Green Cloak Guy, but uses a generator rather than creating a list. This should be a little more memory-friendly with large texts and will allow you to iterate over the chunks lazily. You can turn it into a list with `list()` or use is anywhere an iterator is expected:

```
s = "Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don’t tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist—I really believe he is Antichrist—I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my ‘faithful slave,’ as you call yourself! But how do you do? I see I have frightened you—sit down and tell me all the news."

def get_chunks(s, maxlength):
    start = 0
    end = 0
    while start + maxlength  < len(s) and end != -1:
        end = s.rfind(" ", start, start + maxlength + 1)
        yield s[start:end]
        start = end +1
    yield s[start:]

chunks = get_chunks(s, 25)

#Make list with line lengths:
[(n, len(n)) for n in chunks]
```

**results**

```
[('Well, Prince, so Genoa', 22),
 ('and Lucca are now just', 22),
 ('family estates of the', 21),
 ('Buonapartes. But I warn', 23),
 ('you, if you don’t tell me', 25),
 ('that this means war, if', 23),
 ('you still try to defend', 23),
 ('the infamies and horrors', 24),
 ('perpetrated by that', 19),
 ('Antichrist—I really', 19),
 ('believe he is', 13),
 ('Antichrist—I will have', 22),
 ('nothing more to do with', 23),
 ('you and you are no longer', 25),
 ('my friend, no longer my', 23),
 ('‘faithful slave,’ as you', 24),
 ('call yourself! But how do', 25),
 ('you do? I see I have', 20),
 ('frightened you—sit down', 23),
 ('and tell me all the news.', 25)]
```

Comment: If `s = "aa aa aa aa aa aa aa"` and you call `get_chunks(s, 5)` this will incorrectly return chunks of `"aa "` instead of `"aa aa"`. Otherwise, it's a great solution.

Comment: That's an interesting test case @Dan, thanks. If it returns an chunks of `"aa aa"` it will lose a space— the one between the chunks. It seems it should start with `"aa aa"` and then  the next chunk would be `" aa "`...

Comment: My assumption is that there is a space inferred between the separate elements of the chunked list

Comment: @Dan Yes, thats probably a better way to do it.

Comment: I think that edit deals with it @Dan. I appreciate the feedback — and would be happy to hear of any edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Mark's answer, it looks like there's a small bug in the code when dealing with the end of the search, something like this might work:

```
    def text_to_chunks(s, maxlength):
        start = 0
        end   = 0
        while start + maxlength  < len(s) and end != -1:
            end = s.rfind(" ", start, start + maxlength + 1)
            if end == -1: break
            yield s[start:end]
            start = end +1
        yield s[start:]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `nltk.tokenize` methods as follows:

```
import nltk

corpus = '''
Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don’t tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist—I really believe he is Antichrist—I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my ‘faithful slave,’ as you call yourself! But how do you do? I see I have frightened you—sit down and tell me all the news.” 
'''

tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(corpus)
```

or

```
sent_tokens = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(corpus)
```

Comment: How does this create chunks of a certain size?